# Relation between spatial resolution and object size in satellite imaging

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite

Is there a general rule of thumb that relates the ability of satellite remote sensors to resolve an object and the spatial resolution of the sensors?

For example, a whale that's 15m in length and 7-8 meters in width can not possibly be identified on sentinel-2 imagery which offers 20m spatial resolution but can be identified easily on Worldview 3 images with 10cm spatial resolution.

In general what is the relative spatial resolution required to resolve an object of of a given size? Is it 1:10? 1:5?

Comment: You really need to read up on the basics of remote sensing. In your example you are ignoring the concept of spectral discrimination in leu of purely visual discrimination. If we relied solely on visual discrimination historically, there is very little that could have been accomplished.

Comment: I can remember mapping bores in outback Australia from 10m monochrome satellite imagery, it wasn't the bore that was seen but the 'green' patch around the associated trough and a track that would often terminate at the bore site, no such luck with whales which are indistinguishable in choppy seas. I think you'd have bigger problems mapping whales than the cell size, they like being under water, deep under water, except mother and calf that tend to stick to the surface, except for this you'd only see them if they're coming up for air on in particularly shallow water.

Comment: I think technology has progressed to a point where it has become possible to visually distinguish whales from satellite images. Here is a picture if you don't believe me: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/researchers-can-now-monitor-whales-satellite-180970703/

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Can you please elaborate a little? by spectral discrimination do you mean using different wavelengths like infrared?

Comment: That example is at the surface on a fairly calm day. Some whales stay under for more than an hour, returning to the surface for a few minutes, you would need a series of images taken at no more than 5 minute intervals for over an hour to track the path and then you face the challenge of identifying individuals which requires a much smaller cell size to identify barnacle/pigment/fin pattern unless all you're after is *'whales swim here'* tracks. Infra red isn't so good with water, I think it's green that has good penetration depending on turbidity which is why boats use sonar and not LiDAR.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks! Would you know what spatial resolution would be required to discriminate boars from satellite imagery? Would 5cm be enough? 2cm? What would be the minimum such that you can tell from the image that "this is a boar"?

Comment: For context, we are using cameras mounted on high altitude balloons so the technology definitely exists to zooming on really high resolution. We are trying to identify individual whales from the shape of their flukes (tails) and we want to know the minimum resolution needed for the cameras as higher resolution ones would obviously cost more.

Comment: Bore, not boar. A bore is a hole made with a drill deep into the earth to access artesian and sub-artesian water in an arid climate. A boar is a male pig which are not easy to spot when you're walking through a cane field with a .308 until you're almost on top of them. Fluke identification is difficult, it depends on the size of the variations present in the species then use about half that and machine learning should be able to fill in the rest. How are you intending to geolocate the images? without geolocation the result would be unusable in a GIS system.

Comment: We have successfully used fractional mixture modeling to identify elephants using 30m landsat data. Obviously you cannot "see" an elephant in a lansat pixel so, this is what j mean by relying in spectral, not visual  discrimination. However, water interacting with active sensor wavelengths is an entirely different issue that, in fact would influence feature space but, this was not the the original impetuous of the question.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Right, since we were in an animal-context I assumed it was a typo. So about half of the size of the variation would work? That's good to know. The balloons are GPS-tracked so we would have a rough idea of where the images were taken.

Comment: What about orientation and cell size? You're not going to be able to use auto correlation as the background is constantly changing, your cell size directly relates to your height.. though, it may not be all that bad, equating cell size with accuracy is a trap, the location could be +/- 100m with a cell size of 5cm to differentiate individuals and it may suit your purpose; be sure to state the inaccuracy clearly in your results: *as soon as you make a mark you risk someone assuming it's accurate* like boats running into rock walls as the driver was watching the GPS and not the markers.

Comment: The point I was trying to make with respect to bores is that it's not the bore you see it's the ephemeral effect caused by the existence of a working bore, overflow soaked ground with verdant vegetation, stock tracks and vehicle paths that remain for a surprising long time after the vehicle has passed. Pest species like pigs can be discerned with a large cell size by locating their detrimental effect on vegetation and waterways. With whales the sea is essentially unchanged by their existence, they don't leave a 'game trail' so you will need lots of photos to have any hope of tracking them.

Comment: Thanks for the concern. We don't really need highly accurate GPS coordinates since we are just trying to identify the regions they like to go to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments this question seems less about "resolving an object" than identifying individual objects from imagery. Here's a general approach.

Get a small sample of high-resolution imagery with which your identification algorithm works really well.

Next, reduce its resolution by subsampling. Your identification algorithm will probably work less well. Try different subsampling sizes to create different simulated source resolutions. Compute the accuracy of your algorithm at these resolutions. Keep track of false positives and false negatives or any other error measure appropriate to your scientific need. This subsampling is probably a best-case scenario, since lower resolution data might come from higher up and have more distortions than a purely subsampled high resolution image of the same area. But we're talking ball-parks here.

Now you have a rough measure of how good a particular resolution is at applying your algorithm, and can then decide whether data at a given resolution is good enough for you.

You can use this is a plan for further data collection - such as deciding whether to fly a balloon high and cover more area at a lower resolution or fly lower and cover less area but at a higher resolution. These efficiency trade-offs are your choice.

Comment: This approach definitely works but is a bit time consuming. I was more looking for a quick rule of thumb that will allow us to quickly determine whether or not something is feasible from from the get go without spending too much time on it.

Comment: But it seems like such heuristics don't exist in the community so I guess this is the next best thing.